# Don't work slidesPerView in Swiper. What is at problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-swiper

*Unfortunately, slidesPerView in Swiper does not work, which should display 3 pictures at once:
*

```
        <>
        <swiper-container
          slidesPerView={3}
          spaceBetween={30}
          pagination={{dynamicBullets: true,}}
          loop={true}
          autoplay={true}
          effect='fade'
          modules={[Autoplay, Pagination]}
          className='mySwiperContainerProduct'
         
        >

            {displayedProducts.map((product) => (
            <swiper-slide key={product.id} className="mySwiperSlide">
              <img src={product.photoUrl} alt={product.title} className='mySwiperImg' />
            </swiper-slide>
          ))}
        </swiper-container>
      </>
```

*Unfortunately, I did not find a solution to this problem.*

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).